# installing git on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt, git

I am unable to install git on my ubuntu 12.10 system. I followed-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

`sudo apt-get update` gives me the error-

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

Then some failed to fetch errors and finally-

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I run `sudo apt-get install git`, I get-

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn
  git-email git-gui gitk gitweb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,800 kB/6,824 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  liberror-perl git-man git
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main git-man all 1:1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main git amd64 1:1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have just set up ubuntu and this is the first I tried installing. Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 has reached it End of Life(EOL) and its repositories have been moved to an archive server. Use the link provided by @muru to change your sources to the archive server.

Comment: I would advise you to install a supported version, ie Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 has reached End Of Life and is no longer supported.

You use digitalocean mirrors,

edit your /etc/apt/source.list to:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main 

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
```

and then execute

```
do-release-upgrade
```

This is just a temporary workaround for those who haven't upgraded yet, but still its strongly recommended your system to latest version ASAP, to avail all security updates.